# How can I get a custom outline numbering template in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, formatting

I've seen a few questions around about what I thought was outline numbering, but instead was about headings. I'm specifically talking outline number formatting.

I wish to make an outline in the following format:

`I. caps roman
    A. caps
        1. number
            i. lower roman
            ii. foo
        2. bar
    B. thing
II. also
    A. another
    B. thing
        1. and
        2. so
            i. on`

Is there any extension I could use for this?